# Ionic run android - Permission Issue

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm having troubles to run the command `ionic run android` (I'm using Ionic 2). When I run it like that on my project folder, I get the following error:

shell.js: internal error

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/home/ronanlopes/workspace/hbesco_app/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.chmodSync (fs.js:1168:18)
    at copyFileSync (/home/ronanlopes/workspace/hbesco_app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:41:6)
    at /home/ronanlopes/workspace/hbesco_app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:201:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object._cp (/home/ronanlopes/workspace/hbesco_app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:157:11)
    at Object.cp (/home/ronanlopes/workspace/hbesco_app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/src/common.js:186:23)
    at updateConfigFilesFrom (/home/ronanlopes/workspace/hbesco_app/platforms/android/cordova/lib/prepare.js:97:11)
    at Api.module.exports.prepare (/home/ronanlopes/workspace/hbesco_app/platforms/android/cordova/lib/prepare.js:40:20)
    at Api.prepare (/home/ronanlopes/workspace/hbesco_app/platforms/android/cordova/Api.js:195:45)
```

If I run the commmand with sudo, it gives me the error of not finding ANDROID_HOME (I checked and it's exported).
Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 
sudo -E ionic run android

instead of sudo ionic run android

it will work